# React Native: How to do a TextInput toolbar that moves up with the keyboard?

Tags: react-native

For example, something like Twitter or Yik Yak's Create New Post/Comment on iPhone.

I imagine it has to do with flex for the toolbar as a footer, then some kind of keyboard aware view (not sure which library to use), but haven't been able to successfully put it all together.

Example of separate TextInput with a toolbar above the keyboard:

[image]

Example of a TextInput in the toolbar that moves up & grows with the keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, wrap your component inside

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>your views/components<KeyboardAvoidingView/>
```

And giving it a behavior

> behavior?: enum('height', 'position', 'padding')
>
> contentContainerStyle?: [object Object]
>
> The style of the content container(View) when behavior is 'position'.
>
> keyboardVerticalOffset: number
>
> This is the distance between the top of the user screen and the react
>   native view, may be non-zero in some use cases.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)

Comment: I've kind of got this working the way I want on iOS, however the behavior on Android is kind of whack, I think due to the various keyboard options available for Android e.g. adjustPan, adjustResize, adjustNothing, etc. I don't know which one to use. Is it possible for you to show an example with just a TextInput at the bottom of the screen? I'm definitely not finding this very simple.

Comment: Okay, after more research, it turns out Android doesn't need this at all. It seems to be the case that these keyboard libraries do not work well with Android, and that it just needs `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. iOS does need and works great with `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` as well as `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` and `react-native-keyboard-spacer`, however.

Comment: Weird, i knew about the latter, but i used the KeyboardAvoidingView successfully on android in my last project, which i shipped last week.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't get `KeyboardAvoidingView` or any other libs to work perfectly on Android for the messenger example I was trying to create. They would all just do some whacky, unexpected behavior. Can't speak for other scenarios. I tried getting rid of libs to just use normal `<View />` and added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the manifest. Low and behold it ended up doing exactly what I wanted it to. This also to seems to be what this popular library is doing: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat#android-installation It was "pretty simple" on iOS though!